# Дан селект, инпут и кнопка. Сделайте так, чтобы в инпут можно было что-то ввести и значение изменилось в select

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>123</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <select>
      <option>Выберите героя</option>
      <option>TTV_Wraith</option>
      <option>Pathfinder</option>
      <option>Wattson</option>
      <option>Bloodhound</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p><input type="text"></p>
  <p><input type="submit"></p>
  <script>
    let select = document.querySelector('select'),
      input = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]'),
      submit = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');
    submit.addEventListener('click', function() {
      select[input.value * 1].selected = true;
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, опечатался в названии, изменилось в select

Не могу придумать как реализовать замену, в виду недостатка знаний.
Информации какой-то толковой не нашёл./

Comment: Я ничего не понял.

Comment: Что Вас не устраивает в том, как работает код в вопросе?

Comment: Если кратко, мне нужно ввести текст/число в поле и по нажатию кнопки значение должно измениться в select`е

Comment: Если кратко, это что происходит сейчас. Введите `2` и нажмите кнопку.

Comment: Код в вопросе выводит в поле значение выбранное в select`е, а как сделать так, что бы значение указанное вручную в Input после нажатия кнопки принудительно изменяло значение в select`е..
Например: Выбираем "TTV_Wraith", а после вручную пишем любой текст или цифры, и изменяем значение с "TTV_Wraith" на указанное юзером.

Надеюсь смог объяснить

Comment: Сейчас после нажатия на кнопку ничего не происходит

Comment: Сейчас полсе нажатия на кнопку все происходит. Введите `3` и нажмите кнопку.

Comment: Всё, понял, тогда всё работает.
Видимо пора идти спать) 
Я тут сам протупил, неправильно всё это время читал вопрос задания.
Спасибо за пояснение)

Answer (score 2):

```js
let select = document.querySelector('select'),
  input = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]'),
  submit = document.querySelector('input[type="button"]');
submit.addEventListener('click', function() {
  select[+input.value].selected = true;
});
```

```html
<p>
  <select>
    <option>Выберите героя</option>
    <option>TTV_Wraith</option>
    <option>Pathfinder</option>
    <option>Wattson</option>
    <option>Bloodhound</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p><input type="text" value="2"></p>
<p><input type="button" value="Click"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const select = document.querySelector('select')
const input = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]')
const submit = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]')
const optionsNodeList = select.querySelectorAll('option')
const options = [...optionsNodeList].map(element => element.value)//массив из значений селекта ['Выберите героя','TTV_Wraith', 'Pathfinder' ... ]
options.shift()//удаляем первый элемент из массива ('Выберите героя')

submit.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(options.some(element => element === input.value)) {//проверяем совпадает ли введенное значение в инпуте с хотя бы одним элементом массива options
        select.value = input.value
    }
})
```

```html
<p>
    <select>
        <option>Выберите героя</option>
        <option>TTV_Wraith</option>
        <option>Pathfinder</option>
        <option>Wattson</option>
        <option>Bloodhound</option>
    </select>
</p>

<p><input type="text"></p>

<p><input type="submit"></p>
```